# How to change a field of all objects in a django queryset to a value but I don't want to save it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models `Question` and `Choice`.

Here I want to change the value of all `choice.vote to 0`. But I don't want to update it.

I know I can update the field by calling `query_set.update(field=value)`.

Extra requirements:

- I don't want to affect anything to my database
- also, more importantly, *I want to avoid this nested for loop*.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
updated_choice_list = []
for question in Question.objects.filter(some_condition):
    for choice in question.choice_set.all():
        choice.vote = 0 # I dont want to save the choice vote
        updated_choice_list.append(choice)
```

Comment: But what's the point? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: More context would help. Also showing the model definitions and what you'd want to filter by would help in helping you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What I want to achieve is, for further processing I want to make all choices votes to zero value. But I don't want to save it. I can do this using the above method But It contains nested for loop. So If there is many objects in queryset It takes lots of time. Is there any other way to do this without nested for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't change anything in the database, so that is done.  Depending on your `some_condition` you can remove the nested for loops, by querying the Choices directly:

```
updated_choice_list = Choice.objects.filter(question__some_condition):
for choice in updated_choice_list:
    choice.vote = 0
```

Comment: `updated_choice_list` is a non-cached queryset this means that whenever updated_choice_list would be iterated again it would result in another query. The mutated `choice` is only mutated inside the for loop scope because of this. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#when-querysets-are-not-cached

Comment: Actually, when you iterate over the queryset that first time it will be evaluated and cached, but I agree that it would make sense to explicitly turn it into a list:  `updated_choice_list = list(Choice.objects...`

Answer (score 0):

According to the details you've given this should do it.

```py
choices = [c for c in Choice.objects.filter(question__some_filter=something).all()]
for c in choices:
    c.vote = 0
```